# DataTable JQuery Exporting Sorted GridView to Excel

Tags: datatables

I got a datatable gridview which needs to be export to exel or pdf. When the user sorts the column, I need to export the grid in the same order. So far, I can only export the gridview in the intial state. How do I keep record of the sorted datatable gridview?
Any help is appreciated.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var oResultGrid = $("[id$='gvReportData']");
        if (fixEmptyDataRow(oResultGrid)) {
            var oTable = oResultGrid.dataTable({
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false

            });
        }
        else {
            oResultGrid.dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI" : true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aaSorting": [[0, 'asc']],
                "sDom": '<"top"lif<"clear">>rt<"bottom"lip<"clear">>',
                "bServerSide": false,
                "iDisplayLength":-1,
                "aoColumns": [
                        { "bSortable": true },
                        { "bSortable": true },
                        { "bSortable": true },
                        { "bSortable": true },
                        { "bSortable": true },
                        { "bSortable": true },
                        { "bSortable": true },
                        { "bSortable": true },
                        { "bSortable": true },
                        { "sType": "date-foia" },
                        { "sType": "date-foia" },
                        { "sType": "date-foia" }
                ]
            });
        }
    });


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {


        }
    }


    protected void imgExcel_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        Export.ExportWebControlToExcel(gvReportData, "SnapShot Report");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To export to pdf and excel, [tabletools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) plugin is very useful and by default it extracts the data the way they are sorted in your view. The tabletools use an swf file to do this.

There is also the option of an ActiveX script to make the extraction but that tights you only to IE versions.